# How do I get an html5 video to rewind on click of a button and play forward when the button is clicked again?

Tags: jquery, html, video

My first question, so sorry if I'm making mistakes re:formatting!

My goal is to create a ui where when you land on the page, an html5 video will autoplay. When a button is clicked, the video will rewind. When the button is clicked again, the video will play forwards from the point where the video was rewinding.

http://webdesign.digitalmediauconn.org/SHV02001/Sugar/

Currently, it's just rewinding and clicking on the button again just keeps it rewinding. I only need it to run on Chrome. Everything I've read, even custom buttons, has multiple buttons controlling rewind, fast-forward, etc.

Code:

```
<div class="video-player-box">
  <video id="video" autoplay loop controls>
<source src="video/SugarTestV2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
<!--video player box-->


<div id="buttoncontainer">
  <button id="negative">Rewind</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var video = $("#video");
  var intervalRewind;
  $(video).on('play', function() {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
  });

  $(video).on('pause', function() {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
  });

  $("#negative").click(function() { // button function for rewind
    intervalRewind = setInterval(function() {
      video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      if (video.currentTime == 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalRewind);
        video.pause();
      } else {
        video.currentTime += -.1;
      }
    }, 30);
  });
});
```